# How should we tag the new Dune movie by Denis Villeneuve?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we tag the new ***Dune*** movie by **Denis Villeneuve**?

Should it be [dune-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2021) (the David Lynch one is currently [dune-1984](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-1984))?

Or should it be "dune-part-one" (as the film is apparently [titled on-screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(2021_film)))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy with "Dune-2021"...

Let's not complicate matters with a Part One since we have no idea if Part Two will ever get made.

Comment: [tag:Dune-Part-One] can be a synonym maybe